# perl - search for a long line and change a word in it

Tags: perl

One line bash command: how to search for a long line and change a word in it?

```
 perl -i -0pe 's/my long line/my right line/g' file
```

That works, but can I have some thing more readable
such as

```
perl -i -0pe '\
SEARCH=my long line \
CHANGE=s/long/right/g \
' file
```

I must need to use perl

Comment: you can assign variables and use.. `$search = "my long line";`, `$change = "my right line";` and then `s/$search/$change/g;`... you don't need the ``\`` to continue to next line... also, are you sure you need the `-0` option? It means null character is treated as separator...

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i -0pe '\
$match = quotemeta "my long line";\
$find = quotemeta 'long';\
$replace = 'right';\
s/$find/$replace/g if m/$match/;\
' file
```

As sundeep said you can use variables. Be sure to quotemeta the variables for the match side of the regex